# Postfix-expression evaluation

Tags: c++, stl, stack

I am trying to write a program for evaluating postfix-expression
code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stack>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    char *a=argv[1];
    int n=strlen(a);
    stack<int>s;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if (a[i]=='+')
            s.push(s.pop()+s.pop());
        if (a[i]=='*')
            s.push(s.pop() * s.pop());
        if ((a[i]>='0') && (a[i]<='9'))
            s.push(0);
        while ((a[i]>='0') && (a[i]<='9'))
            s.push(10*s.pop()+(a[i++]-'0'));
    }
    cout<<s.pop()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But errors says that

```
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\compilers\compilers.cpp(16): error C2296: '*' : illegal, left operand has type 'void'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\compilers\compilers.cpp(16): error C2297: '*' : illegal, right operand has type 'void'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\compilers\compilers.cpp(21): error C2297: '*' : illegal, right operand has type 'void'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\compilers\compilers.cpp(25): error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'void' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

I thought that I have a stack of type string or type char, but neither works. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: I would strongly recommend 'char const* const a = argv[1]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**pop**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/pop/) function justs pops but does not return anything.

You should use the [**top**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/top/) to get the top value and then call `pop`

So

```
s.push(s.pop() * s.pop());
```

should be changed to:

```
int temp1 = s.top();
s.pop();
int temp2 = s.top();
s.pop();
s.push(temp1 * temp2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://thecspoint.blogspot.in/2017/05/postfix-expression-evaluation.html) may help you to solve your problem.